Dynmaic workers and concurrency changing possiable in pub/sub using redis ,node and bull
Dynmaic workers and concurrency  changing  possiable in pub/sub using redis ,node and bull
I am using redis ,node,bull and i want to change my workers and concurrency dynamically according to system resource and number of worker need to process jobes.
How to achieve this things dynamically
const MAX_CONCURRENCY = 10; // Maximum number of concurrent workers
const MIN_CONCURRENCY = 1; // Minimum number of concurrent workers

const RESOURCE_THRESHOLD = {
    cpu: 0.8, // 80% CPU usage threshold
    memory: 70 // 70% memory usage threshold (in percentage)
};

// Worker function to process the queue
async function processJob(job) {
    const { domain } = job.data;
    console.log(`Processing job for domain: ${domain}`);
    
    try {
        await runSubdomainEnumeration(domain); // Example task
        job.progress(100);
        console.log(`Completed processing for domain: ${domain}`);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(`Error processing domain: ${domain}`, error);
        // If job fails, send to another queue
        throw error;
    }
}

// Function to get memory usage percentage
function getMemoryUsagePercentage() {
    const totalMemory = os.totalmem();
    const freeMemory = os.freemem();
    const usedMemory = totalMemory - freeMemory;
    return (usedMemory / totalMemory) * 100;
}

// Function to generate a random ID
function generateRandomId() {
    return Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 9); // Generates a random alphanumeric string
}

// Function to adjust concurrency based on system resources
function adjustConcurrency() {
    // Monitor CPU usage
    osUtils.cpuUsage((cpuUsage) => {
        const memoryUsage = getMemoryUsagePercentage();

        if (cpuUsage < RESOURCE_THRESHOLD.cpu && memoryUsage < RESOURCE_THRESHOLD.memory && concurrency < MAX_CONCURRENCY) {
            // Scale up concurrency if resources are available
            concurrency += 1;
            console.log(`Scaling up concurrency to ${concurrency}`);
            monitoringQueue.process(generateRandomId(), concurrency, processJob); // Adjust processing with new concurrency
        } else if ((cpuUsage > RESOURCE_THRESHOLD.cpu || memoryUsage > RESOURCE_THRESHOLD.memory) && concurrency > MIN_CONCURRENCY) {
            // Scale down concurrency if resources are above thresholds
            concurrency -= 1;
            console.log(`Scaling down concurrency to ${concurrency}`);
            monitoringQueue.process(concurrency, processJob); // Adjust processing with new concurrency
        }
    });
}

// Adjust concurrency every second
setInterval(adjustConcurrency, 1000);

